# How to factor $x + 1 - 2 \sqrt x$?

Tags: factoring

My teacher said the answer is $(\sqrt x -1)^2$, but I want to know how he figured it out. I know it's a trick I learned years ago, but I can't remember how to do this.

Comment: Hint: $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$

Comment: By the way, it is frowned upon if you do not select best answers. I am looking at your activity and you have a few that have not been selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $y:=\sqrt x$ to get $y^2-2y+1$

Comment: What does $:=$ mean? How do I read that? I am just assuming that $y:=x$ for example reads as "$y$ such that it is equal to $x$" ??

Answer (score 5):

This is a quadratic in $\sqrt{x}$. If you let $\sqrt{x} = y$, this becomes $y^2 - 2y - 1$ which can be factorized.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
x + 1 − 2\sqrt{x}&=x + 1 − \sqrt{x}- \sqrt{x}\\
&= x − \sqrt{x} + 1 - \sqrt{x}\\
&= \sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x} - 1) - 1(\sqrt{x} - 1)\\
&= (\sqrt{x} - 1)(\sqrt{x} - 1)\\
&= (\sqrt{x} - 1)^{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Would you care to fix $\LaTeX$, Please

Comment: I am new to stackexchange. I hope it pleases you.

Comment: That's obvious, [Refer This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)